# Is there any ways or functions to connect and interpolate points into the Multidigraph generated by OSMnx?

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

New to GIS and OSMnx, thank you for your help!

Konwn:
One area generated by Osmnx,
Several points with (lon, lat) coordinates in the area (I think that is what we call 'POI')

Question:
How to connect and interpolate this ponits to the area, and then merge then into a new Multidigraph that can be handled by OSMnx. (I want to calculate the shortest path of nodes in the new graph, so I have to merge it first.)

If you need specific data and area of the aforementioned konwn part, please let me know and I will attach it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to create the new Multidigraph from the points, using the `Multidigraph.from_points()` method:

`Multidigraph.from_points(points, source_id='puntos_osm')` #source_id is optional

`Multidigraph(points=[[(37.23, -121.39), (37.21, -121.39), (37.22, -121.41)], [(37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39)], [(37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39)], [(37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39)], [(37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39)], [(37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39)]], id='multido')`

The next step is to interpolate the points using the interpolation package.

`from interpolate import Interpolate` # you can use your own interpolation routine if you want

Multidigraph.from_points(points, source_id='puntos_osm')
interpolated = Interpolate(interpolate_kwargs={'method': 'nearest'})
Multidigraph(points=[[(37.23, -121.39), (37.21, -121.39), (37.22, -121.41)], [(37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39)], [(37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39)], [(37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39)], [(37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39)], [(37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39)]], id='multido')

#### Merging the new Multidigraph into the destination Multidigraph

The new Multidigraph can be now merged into the destination Multidigraph, using the Multidigraph.merge_from() method:
destination_multidigraph.merge_from(interpolated, source_id='interpolated')
Destination Multidigraph:

`Multidigraph(points=[[(37.23, -121.39), (37.21, -121.39), (37.22, -121.41)], [(37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39)], [(37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39)], [(37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39)], [(37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39)], [(37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39)], [(37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39)], [(37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39)], [(37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39)], [(37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39), (37.23, -121.39)]], id='destination_multido')`

This new Multidigraph can now be used as a source for any other Osmnx methods. For example, it can be converted to a Shapely Polygon
`destination_multidigraph.to_poly(name='merged_multido') (37.23 -121.39, 37.21 -121.39, 37.22 -121.41)`

Comment: First, you will need to convert the data to lines. Then, you will need to make a polygon out of the new lines. Finally, merge the polygon into a Multidigraph.

Comment: There is no function named '''Multidigraph.from_points()'''

Comment: is not a function but a method. Function: Standalone feature or functionality.
Method: One way of doing something, which has different approaches or methods, but is related to the same aspect, a class. In case you don't feel comfortable using multidigraph you can use DiGraph.() which is a function

Comment: [info](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/multidigraph.html) here is the dommentations to read more about the differences.

Comment: Frankly speaking, far from my idea, thanks anyway.